# Using Aptana Studio to import git project but Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: github, permissions, aptana

I tried to import an existing project from the github repository into aptana studio but an error says Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I made sure to add my ssh to my account in github. I also ran $ssh -vT gitt@github.com 
and this is what it says that the private key cannot be found.

On other windows 7 machine I never had a problem importing a Git project but on my home PC I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently this has to do with the proper ssh - keys to be set with aptana. There are two possibilities
1) If you've installed the github for Windows application than you already have a key-pair. It will also be already registered with Github. You can find these under https://github.com/settings/ssh once you've logged on to github.
Now you need to explain aptana to use the proper private key for that open Aptana and

1. go to Window/Preferences -> General/Network Connections/SSH2
2. Click Add Private Key... and select the github_rsa file, not the pub
   file, we want to tell aptana what your private key is.

Now aptana will use the proper key to connect to github

Comment: I figured out my problem.  Be sure to paste the https url that github gives you into the uri field of Aptana, rather than using the git url that Aptana grabs after you log in.

Comment: Pasting the URI worked for me,  nothing else I did would get rid of that publickey denied message

Comment: @mattblang  you need to add that as an answer.  worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem as follows:

- I copied the "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub" files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh\

My setup:
- I used git for windows from http://git-scm.com/download/win
- I told Aptana to use this executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe

Now finally Aptana could do git pull with the SSH keys. Seems the Team > Pull option doesn't "see" the machine's local ssh keys.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug of Aptana Studio.
Of course you can just use the https to login, but it is not a solution for ssh key.
You may configure ssh key following [this](http://falahati.net/my-blog/98-aptana-and-git-through-ssh-problem#.U42JKHJ_tKY).

Comment: This was my issue. Had to use process monitor (procmon.exe) to find where Aptana's ssh-agent.exe was looking for the key (filtered procmon output on process like "ssh"), then copied the keys to that folder. Aptana (as of v3.6.0) ignores the settings made in Preferences->General->Network Connections->SSH2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by generating new ssh keys. Just install Git at http://git-scm.com/download/win and using Git Bash follow this guidelines at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys.

Good luck.