# Windows Aptana SSH Git to private repository - fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: windows, git, ssh, aptana

When trying to import a git repository as a new project, I always get this error (no more, no less) on Windows:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't get any other errors and I'm not sure where to check for better error logs.

I enter my URI:

```
ssh://user@server:port/my/directory/repo.git
```

And it fails. However, I use the same URI on a Mac or Linux pc running Aptana and it works. What gives? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Following questions may give some pointers: ["Permission Denied (publickey)/fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19471599/2419207) and ["Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15240815/2419207)

Comment: I have seen those already, but I don't believe it's a public key issue. And I'm not totally sure if the second is relevant.

Comment: Maybe ["Using Aptana Studio to import git project but Permission denined (publickey)"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16449099/2419207) is somehow related to your problem?

Comment: Or ["Git fatal: remote end hung up"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1493645/2419207)? You may want to provide some details about how git is set up on your system, otherwise it's rather difficult to find out what causes described problem.

Comment: So does `ssh -Tvvv ssh://user@server:port` works? (in order to rule out a public key issue)

Comment: @VonC, that is irrelevant because the field in the Aptana form only asks for a URI. Unless there is a way to change the settings for git repos, I couldn't test a line like that.